# Sum the counts of specific subarrays in 3d array

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum

I need to count the child of an array. My array output as below.
I'm able to count the first step but I need to count the [address] values which is at the second step.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Los Angeles
                    [1] => San Francisco
                )

            [presenter] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jane Doe
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => New York
                    [1] => Chicago
                )

            [presenter] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )   
)
```

Comment: `$count = count($myArray[0]['address'];`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count all the address values, there are various ways to do it. Here are a couple of possibilities:

```
$address_count = array_reduce($your_array, function($count, $item) {
    return $count + count($item['address']);
}, 0);

// or

$address_count = array_sum(array_map('count', array_column($your_array, 'address')));

// or

$address_count = 0;
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    $address_count += count($item['address']);
}
```